# My AsyncTask does not update UI smoothly (animation)

Tags: android-asynctask, android-animation, android

I want to make a `TextView` appear little by little, like animation. The problem is, the animation is not smooth. It gets stuck for a little while sometimes and then resumes. Sometimes even worse, it goes back... I mean, the `TextView` gets bigger and bigger but suddenly gets smaller then bigger again. Could anyone help me?

```
private class UnfoldTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Integer> {

    View view;

    public UnfoldTask(View v) {
        this.view = v;
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams pa = view.getLayoutParams();
        pa.height = 0;
        view.setLayoutParams(pa);
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Integer... maxHeight) {
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams pa = view.getLayoutParams();
        while (pa.height < maxHeight[0]) {
                pa.height += (int) (24 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density + 0.5f);
                sleep(100);
                publishProgress(pa.height);
        }
        return maxHeight[0];
    }

    private void sleep(int i) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(i);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams pa = view.getLayoutParams();
        pa.height = values[0];
        view.setLayoutParams(pa);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams pa = view.getLayoutParams();
        pa.height = result;
        view.setLayoutParams(pa);
    }
}
```

Comment: you should probably use an [animation](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/index.html) for this, not an AsyncTask. AsyncTasks are run in the background **indeterminately** -- which means they will run when they run, but there are no guarantees on how soon that will be

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a scale animation for this. Here's an example:

```
ScaleAnimation animation = new ScaleAnimation(1, 2, 1, 2, centerX, centerY); // Scales from normal size (1) to double size (2). centerX/Y is the center of your text view. Change this to set the pivot point of your animation.
animation.setDuration(1000);
myTextView.startAnimation(animation);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [droidQuery](http://phil-brown.github.io/droidQuery/) to simplify this:

```
//this will set the height of myView to 0px.
$.with(myView).height(0);

//when you are ready to animate to height (in pixels):
$.with(myView).animate("{height:" + height + "}", new AnimationOptions());
```

Check the documentation if you want to get fancy - such as adding duration, and event callbacks. If you are still noticing non-smooth animation, consider adding the *application attribute* to your *AndroidManifest*:

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```